# Deadpool in X-Men Origins: Wolverine

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, x-men-origins-wolverine

When Stryker activates Wade (which is known as weapon XI) in *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* he refers to him as the "Deadpool". I recently watched the Deadpool movie and even though he has regeneration, he lacks all the other powers showed when weapon XI fights Victor and Wolverine.

Why this discrepancy?

Comment: Because they aren't the same Deadpool.

Comment: Short answer: they screwed it up in the first movie.